# Where can I find the data sheet for the SPI&I2C interface chip used in the 8-pin versions of the OV5642 ArduCAM?

Tags: arduino, camera

I have an OV5642 ArduCam with the 8-pin interface.  This module has a RAM buffer and a chip to translate from SPI & I2C into the MIPI/DVP used by the camera module.

I have found https://www.arducam.com/downloads/shields/ArduCAM_Mini_5MP_Camera_Shield_Hardware_Application_Note.pdf and it documents the registers, but I suspect it is not complete.  I can not get any identifying info for the chip because it is under a heat sink (which can get really hot if you aren't operating in power-saving mode)

One thing not explained by that document is register 7 which is written to in one of the example sketches: https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino/blob/3577fbd1b5a9f4afbe9923718fa0f265d671dc3a/ArduCAM/examples/mini/ArduCAM_Mini_5MP_OV5640_Plus_Functions/ArduCAM_Mini_5MP_OV5640_Plus_Functions.ino#L52

Another is https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino/blob/3577fbd1b5a9f4afbe9923718fa0f265d671dc3a/ArduCAM/examples/mini/ArduCAM_Mini_5MP_OV5640_Plus_Functions/ArduCAM_Mini_5MP_OV5640_Plus_Functions.ino which is represents a bunch of register writes to configure resolutions and formats.  (used by the `wrSensorRegs16_8()` method at https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino/blob/3577fbd1b5a9f4afbe9923718fa0f265d671dc3a/ArduCAM/ArduCAM.cpp#L2997 )

Those `sensor_reg` tuples reference registers like 0x3103 and 0x401d, which are not documented in the PDF from arducam.com.

Where can I find documentation that would let me understand these register writes?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found https://www.uctronics.com/download/cam_module/OV5642DS.pdf which seems to include descriptions of the registers that have a 16-bit address.  I have not yet found the description of register 0x7